# C++ 3 level map

Tags: c++, dictionary, iteration, stdmap

I am using a multilevel map

```
map<string, map<string, map<string, int>>> _myMap;
```

How to access the integer value using the iterator of outermost map only?

Please help me in finding suitable references for 3-level map too.

Comment: You can't there is not such thing as one integer in the second and third map. You need to specify the key for the second and the third map to obtain the integer.

Comment: Also, containers of containers of containers has a real code smell to it. You should look at modelling this another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following to retrieve the 'first' inner int (Assuming there exist).

```
int i = it->second.begin()->second.begin()->second;
```

To iterate over all values, you may use:

- C++11:

  ```
  for (/*const*/ auto& p1 : _myMap) {
      const std::string& s1 = p1.first;
      for (/*const*/ auto& p2 : p1.second) {
          const std::string& s2 = p2.first;
          for (/*const*/ auto& p3 : p2.second) {
              const std::string& s3 = p3.first;
              /*const*/ int& value = p3.second;

              // Do what you want.
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- C++03:

  ```
  typedef map<string, int> map3;
  typedef map<string, map3> map2;
  typedef map<string, map2> map1;

  for (map1::/*const_*/iterator it1 = _myMap.begin(), end1 = _myMap.end(); it1 != end1; ++it1) {
      const std::string& s1 = it1->first;
      for (map2::/*const_*/iterator it2 = it1->second.begin(), end2 = it1->second.end(); it2 != end2; ++it2) {
          const std::string& s2 = it2->first;
          for (map3::/*const_*/iterator it3 = it2->second.begin(), end3 = it2->second.end(); it3 != end3; ++it3) {
              const std::string& s3 = it3->first;
              /*const*/ int& value = it3->second;

              // Do what you want.
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: how to access further integer values?

Answer (score 1):

```
int myInt = (((*it).second)["index"])["index"];
```

You can also regenerate a new map with the iterator and iterate througth it.

Comment: I believe you meant `it->second["index"]["index"]`

Comment: Hum I'm confused now, yours looks better but isn't it the same?

Comment: @Mayerz `second` is not a function.

Comment: You can't have the `()` right after `second` - it's not a function.

Comment: No, it's not. Getting mine as close as possible to yours (but still correct) gives this: `(((*it).second)["index"])["index"]`. `second` is not a function, it can't be called. And `.` binds tighter than `*`.

Comment: For sure @Angew, I just put the parenthesis for the sake of the map context, I didn't got you the first time because I totally forgotten that second wasn't a member func. Sorry again!

Comment: Still incorrect. Yours gives precedence `*(it.second)`, you meant `(*it).second`

Comment: Yep, I usually dont answer, but It looked so easy that I didnt even tryed it, next time I'll check it first.